# i want to know what's difference between two closure:

Tags: javascript, closures

i want to know what's difference between two closures:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
   // JS code
})(window);
```

another

```
(function(window) {
   // JS code
})(window, undefined);
```

Comment: Note that how Javascript handles things when the number of declared function arguments doesn't match the number of arguments included in the function call is not related to the concept of closures, nor is how `undefined` works.

Comment: Note that passing *window* is somewhat pointless, since if it's been assigned some value other than a reference to the pseudo–global object expected in browsers, you get that value. Much better to pass in *this*, which unequivocally references the global (window in a browser) object.

Comment: @RobG that will not always be the case. In a "use strict" environment `this` is going to end up being undefined the majority of the time.

Comment: @Norguard—I think you misunderstood my comment. The *this* value in the global execution context is **always** the global object, in strict mode or not, so passing it into a global IIFE is common (e.g. `(function(global){...}(this))`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running in an old, pre-ES5 environment (eg. Internet Explorer 8), `undefined` is just a variable and can be overridden.

Meaning, you can do this:

```
undefined = 42
console.log(undefined) // 42
```

When you pass in 1 argument to your closure (`window`), but your closure function expects 2 arguments (`window`, `undefined`), `undefined` will be, well, undefined. This is to protect against some other code on the page overwriting `undefined`.